# Query Org's Certificates in Apex using Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, soap, certificates

I am unable to retrieve the Certificates of an org using the [Financial Force Metadata API Apex Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) although I see the object in the Metadata API Documentation and can query it using the workbench.

**When I call:**

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();  

MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery query = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
query.type_x = 'Certificate';

for(MetadataService.FileProperties prop : service.listMetadata(new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>{ query }, 25)) {
    System.debug(prop.fullName);
}
```

**I get:**

> Line: 13524, Column: 1 System.CalloutException: Web service callout
>   failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_TYPE: Cannot use:
>   Certificate in this version faultcode=sf:INVALID_TYPE faultactor=

I also tried "certs", "cert", "certificates" for `query.type_x`.

*Note: this is breaking down my issues of [Create Certificate/SSO Config in Apex using Metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271012) into multiple questions as I didn't get any helpful feedback there.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to query the Certificates using the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/) instead:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,DeveloperName+FROM+' +  type);
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

ToolinApiResponse response = (ToolinApiResponse)
                                JSON.deserialize(new Http().send(request).getBody(), ToolinApiResponse.class);
```